# Give different links to results fetched from sql query

Tags: sql, database, hyperlink

I have a database table named restaurants containing fields restaurant_id restaurant_name. I need to fetch this data and make the restaurant name linked to an internal page which contains a description of the restaurant. I have used php to fetch the results but don't know how to add separate links to separate restaurant names that appears after fetching the data. Thanks in advance

Comment: Give some more details, for example: Where is the restaurant description stored? What have you tried so far? Also take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Once your php retrieves the data for the restaurant, just echo some `<a href` links into the output response.  If you are using AJAX to make this query then the client should take the html response and append it to an element on the page.

Comment: Thanks Lochemage but it could add only the same link to all the restaurants that the query was fetching.  So far I had tried to add the links seperately but the same link gets added to all. The description of the restaurant is on a html page whose link is also stored in the same table where the restaurant name and restaurant id are stored.                                          

                
?>

Comment: In that case, I would double check and make sure the links within your database are actually different/correct, and then I would make sure your select statement is actually pulling the proper database tables